# PHP session back button?

Tags: php, html

Ok. So I am using Sessions to store data because I am making a multi page form. The thing is, I need a back button with it. I have a submit button that will take the user to the next page and store the data into sessions but I need a back button next to the submit button in case they messed up for whatever reason. Is there anyway to make a back button with php that will take them back to the previous page while showing the data they entered? heres my code of one page.
Also, I have tried using the history.go but that only works for one page.

```
<?php

//let's start the session
session_start();

//now, let's register our session variables
$_SESSION['opinion1'] = 'opinion1';
$_SESSION['choice1'] = 'choice1';

//finally, let's store our posted values in the session variables
$_SESSION['opinion1'] = $_POST['opinion1'];
$_SESSION['choice1'] = $_POST['choice1'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="pull-left">Securing the Future of Village Walk</h1>
        <div class="pull-right">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ammendment">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="page4_form.php">
            <textarea id="opinion2" name="opinion2" value=""></textarea>
            <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="Yes">
            <label for="No">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="No">
            <label for="Neither">Neither</label>
            <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="Neither">
            **I NEED BACK BUTTON HERE**
            <input type="submit" value="Next">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just check to see if the input has a valid session value saved. If so, update the form field accordingly.

Comment: but how would I make a back button without having the form be resubmitted everytime?

Comment: Anything to do with CSS here? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an additional form like so:

`<form action="pageX.php" method="post>
  <input name="submitBackButton" type="submit" value="Back">
</form>`

This can be detected as a normal GET / POST field within PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitBackButton']))
{
    // Do required actions here
}
```

Comment: But could you put the required actions for me haha? I'm not good with php.

Comment: and also does that work without having the user resubmit the form everytime?

Comment: What actions do you want to take place?

And the above code requires a form submission/page request. If you would to handle it 'dynamically' without a form resubmission then you would have to look into client side scripting - javascript.

Comment: Well when the user hits the back button, I want it to take them to the previous page. On the previous page, i want it to show the form with the input they have already put in the form.

Comment: also, if theres a way so it will resubmit the form automatically without telling the user. at least it tells me on google chrome whenever i go back to resubmit

Comment: You would have to modify the value attributes within the HTML input tags.

Example: 
`<input type="radio" name="choice1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['choice1']; ?>">`

Comment: But I do that on the next page at the beginning, thats why it posts to the next page. At the beginning of the next page, i have this
<?php
 
//let's start the session
session_start();
 
//now, let's register our session variables
$_SESSION['opinion1'] = 'opinion1';
$_SESSION['choice1'] = 'choice1';
 
//finally, let's store our posted values in the session variables
$_SESSION['opinion1'] = $_POST['opinion1'];
$_SESSION['choice1'] = $_POST['choice1'];
 
?>

Comment: it registers the information and puts it into my sessions. I just need a back button that will bring me back to the previous page with the form still filled out when the user hit next

Comment: I don't understand where exactly you are encountering an issue?

Comment: In the code, I showed you, im not. I'm saying the code you said to put into my form on one of the options, is already on my next page. It's already stored into a session so the part you told me is not needed.

Comment: I've edited my answer. This would literally redirect you to the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

I would first organize session data in a way that it's easy for you to correlate data entered with the page it was entered.

One possibility could be to organize session data in an array:

```
$_SESSION['formData'] = array(
    array(... data for step 1 ),
    array(... data for step 2 ),
    array(... data for step 3 ),
);
```

So `$formData[0]` would hold data entered in step 1, etc.

As for the button, another submit would be enough:

```
<input type="submit" value="Back" />
```

Then, you would have to determine which page you are going back to; which you can achieve by sending a hidden field with the current page number.

```
<form method="post" action="page_form.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="X" />
```

One thing to note here is that the server side process would not longer be one-per-page; instead there would be only one `page_form.php` where you'll have to determine the action and the page to move to (although you could use one per page and set the right action in the , there's always several solutions to any problem):

```
<?php
... 

$page = $_POST['page'];
if ( isset($_POST['Back']) ) // Going back
{
    $page -= 1; // Previous page requested 

    // Retrieve data from session
    $data = $_SESSION['formData'][$page-1]; // $page-1 because of zero based array indexes. 

    ...

    // Dynamically load the proper page processor. 
    // each pageX_form.php will know how to deal with the variable $data. 
    include  "page{$page}_form.php" 
}
else
{
    $page += 1; // Next page requested
    $data = $_POST; // In this case, the data is whatever was entered
}
```

When building the form for each page, you'd have to remember to add the hidden field with the page number:

```
<form method="post" action="page_form.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />
```

If you wanted to use one server-side process per page, then you could do something like this instead:

```
<form method="post" action="page<?php echo $page; ?>_form.php">
```

The server-side process would look different, since you would not have to ask for the page number; it would be implicit.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think i got it. So there's technically only 1 page but the other parts of the form are hidden? And then when they click next, it takes them to the next hidden page and vice versa. Is that correct? Also, do you think you could do me a favor and possibly take my code and implement yours, I'm not too good with php

Comment: Not necessarily hidden. 
For a two steps input process. You'd have one single form_process.php where you'd start session, determine if the Back button was pressed, and setting the variables as shown in the answer.
Then you would have other two files: form_part-1.php and form_part-2.php which you would **include** as needed.
As for your request: That's actually how I make a living. I wold gladly help you but I'm not even sure if that kind of discussions is even allowed here.